# Image processing pipeline for a stereo camera feed

Tags: ros, stereo-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My first real ROS project involves detecting lines in a video feed coming from a Zed stereo camera.

I know how I would do this on a single camera feed; the opencv_apps package does most of the work for me.  And while I could simply create a pipeline for each feed, that seems inelegant. The edge_detection and hough_lines nodes don't care whether the image is coming from the left or right camera, so why have one node that subscribes to the left_frame and publishes to left_edges, and a second node that subscribes to right_frame, does the exact same processing, and then publishes to right_edges?

However, the edge_detection node only subscribes to one topic, and only publishes to one topic. My current idea is a relay node that merges the two streams and republishes their messages on a single topic (in a new message type that also contains the information a node at the other end would need to split them again). I could also just combine the images themselves, but I would prefer to keep them separate to simplify some processing later in the pipeline that involves a particular area of the feed. As a last resort, I could fork opencv_apps and add a second subscriber and publisher to the nodes I need. Or I could simply forgo the use of opencv_apps and write an all-in-one processing node.

I imagine that this type of problem is not unique. What other solutions have people come up with? Is there a particular way of handling this that is considered standard/ideal/best practice?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253016/image-processing-pipeline-for-a-stereo-camera-feed/) by [JeffAlan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28683/jeffalan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-01-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can use nodelet to load two edge detector into one process.

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="manager" args="manager"/>

  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="left_edge_detector"
        args="load edge_detection/edge_detection manager">
    <remap from="image" to="left/image_raw" />
    <param name="debug_view" value="false" />
  </node>
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="right_edge_detector"
        args="load edge_detection/edge_detection manager">
    <remap from="image" to="right/image_raw" />
    <param name="debug_view" value="false" />
  </node> 

  <node pkg="image_view" type="image_view" name="left_edge_viewer">
    <remap from="image" to="left_edge_detector/image" />
  </node>
  <node pkg="image_view" type="image_view" name="right_edge_viewer">
    <remap from="image" to="right_edge_detector/image" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) with karma: 1186 on 2017-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1